# toLocaleString api is not working for hi-IN locale

Tags: javascript, localization

```js
var number = 3500;
console.log(number.toLocaleString("hi-IN"));
```

Expected: ३,५००
Actual: 3,500
Browser: Chrome
I am not getting ३,५०० instead i am getting 3,500

Comment: I am getting "3500" and not the ३,५००

Comment: So what is your expected result and what you get now?

Comment: expected  : ३,५०० and i get 3500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Number format locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Parameters)

[`toLocaleString` params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Parameters)

```js
var number = 3500;
console.log(number.toLocaleString("hi-u-nu-deva"));
```

> "u"
>   (Unicode) extension, which can be used to request additional customization of Collator, NumberFormat, or DateTimeFormat objects
>
> "nu"
>   The numbering system to be used. Possible values include: "arab", "arabext", "bali", "beng", "**deva**", "fullwide", "gujr", "guru", "hanidec", "khmr", "knda", "laoo", "latn", "limb", "mlym", "mong", "mymr", "orya", "tamldec", "telu", "thai", "tibt".

Comment: Nice it is working but i only know hi-IN as the locale at runtime.

Comment: is there any way only number.toLocaleString("hi-IN") will work

Comment: why number.toLocaleString("hi-IN") is working for otheres

Comment: @VishalPatil I think it depends on system configuration